# How to get the line number of GLSL compiler error

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glsl

I would like to know if there is a common way of getting the line number of an GLSL compiler error. 
At first I thought I could parse glGetInfoLogARB but then i read that its output is not standardized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not standardized, but among individual vendors it more or less is.

#### For example, NVIDIA tends to output messages that reference lines this way:

```
<Shader String Index>:<Line Number>(<Character Number>): <warning|error|...>:
```

While not perfect, an approach you could take if you needed to parse the info log for line numbers is to pre-process the input based on the `GL_VENDOR` string. The info log is usually for human interpretation though, so I am not sure how much effort this is really worth.

Speaking of non-standard things, `glGetInfoLogARB (...)` is archaic (it only exists in [`GL_ARB_shader_objects`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_objects.txt)).

When GLSL went core in GL 2.0, the function was split into `glGetShaderInfoLog (...)` and `glGetProgramInfoLog (...)` for compiler and linker information respectively. For portability sake, you should not be using the old ARB extension; target GL 2.0 as your minimum version and use core GLSL instead.